# Date function not working with bind_result

Tags: php, mysql, function, date, datetime

I have this date format in place in my files. It works great if I do a normal `SELECT` query, but when I do a prepared statement query that does not have a `bind_param` and assign it a `bind_result` variable, I cannot get this to work.

Here is the function. Which it displays in US Central time. How can I get that to Eastern time?

```
function fixDate($strDateTime) {

 $strFormat = 'M, j, Y';
    $strFormatTime = '\a\t g:ia';
    $intTimeStamp = strtotime($strDateTime);
    $strDate = date($strFormat, $intTimeStamp);
    $strTime = date($strFormatTime, $intTimeStamp);

    if($strDate == date($strFormat)) {
        return "Today " . $strTime;
    }
    elseif($strDate == date($strFormat, strtotime('yesterday'))) {
        return "Yesterday " . $strTime;
    }
    else {
        return " on " . $strDate . " " . $strTime;
    }
}
```

The function will work if I do this with a normal `SELECT` query.

```
$date = $row2['topic_date'];
$date = fixDate($date);
```

BUT if I have a bind_result of `$date` and try to do this

```
$date = fixDate($date);
```

It won't work.

How can I get this function to work with a prepared statement's bind_result variable?

UPDATE:

This works..

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_topics
    INNER JOIN forum_categories ON
    forum_topics.category_id = forum_categories.id
    INNER JOIN users
    ON forum_topics.topic_creator = users.id
    ORDER BY forum_topics.topic_reply_date DESC
    LIMIT 3")
    or die ("Query2 failed: %s\n".($query2->error));
    $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
    if($numrows2 > 0){

    $topics .= "<table class='top_posts_table'>";
    $topics .= "<tr><th class='top_posts_th'>Topic Title</th><th class='top_posts_th'>Replies</th><th class='top_posts_th'>Views</th></tr>";
    $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'><hr /></td></tr>";
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        $cid = $row2['cid'];
        $tid = $row2['id'];
        $title = $row2['topic_title'];
        $views = $row2['topic_views'];
        $replies = $row['tid2'];
        $date = $row2['topic_date'];
        $date = fixDate($date);
        $creator = $row2['username'];
        $topics .= "<tr><td class='top_posts_td'><a href='forum_view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>".$title."</a><br /><span class='post_info'>Posted 
        by: ".$creator."<br>".$date."</span></td><td class='top_posts_td'>0</td><td class='top_posts_td'>".$views."</td></tr>";
        $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'><hr /></td></tr>";
```

This doesn't work...

```
  if ($announcements_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT announcements.id, announcements.user_id, announcements.message, announcements.date, users.username FROM announcements
                        INNER JOIN users
                        ON announcements.user_id = users.id")) {

    $announcements_stmt->execute();
    $announcements_stmt->bind_result($announcements_id, $announcements_user_id, $announcements_messages, $announcements_date, $announcements_username); 

    if (!$announcements_stmt) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }
 }   

$announcements_stmt->store_result();
         $announcements_result = array();
            $announcements_date = $announcements_date;
            $announcements_date = fixDate($announcements_date);
?>
                <div class="index_announcements_out">
                    <div id="announcements_title">League Announcements:</div>
                    <div class="index_announcements_wrap">
                        <table class="index_announcements_table">   
<?php
        while ($row = $announcements_stmt->fetch()) {
?>
                            <tr class="index_announcements_border">
                                <td class="index_announcement_pic"></td>
                                <td class="index_announcement_username_td">FROM: <?php echo $announcements_username; ?><br>on <?php echo $announcements_date; ?></td>
                                <td class="index_announcement_message_td"><?php echo $announcements_messages; ?></td>
                            </tr>
```

Comment: You talk about having an issue with the database functions, but you've not provided any code that uses it...

Comment: So, you mention SELECT works, and using bind_param doesn't but you don't think it's anything to do with the code you haven't provided? Okay then. Good luck.

Comment: Do you have `mysqlnd` installed? If so, you could try [get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) instead of `bind_result`

Comment: No, I don't have it installed.

Comment: Post the query and the way you bind the params in order to help u.

Comment: @Paul Chances are the what you're doing with the binds is wrong. (Yes, I meant bind_result in my previous comment, not bind_param). But without seeing the code, we won't know what's really going on.

Comment: Added the code to my question for what works and what doesn't.

Comment: `var_dump($announcements_date);` after the fixDate call and post result.

Comment: string(27) " on Dec, 31, 1969 at 6:00pm".

Comment: The regular date part works for that query though, so it doesn't have anything to do with the date not being in the db.

Comment: What about a var_dump before the fixDate call?

Comment: Hang on a sec, you're not actually doing a `fetch()`.

Comment: It shows up NULL. This is the part I am confused about structuring. I was just trying to model it after the way I did the normal query way. I am confused with what to do here... `$announcements_date = $announcements_date`

Comment: @Paul You can get rid of that line. It doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: All of my results are displaying though.

Comment: The correct date is displaying, just not in the format I want it to be from the function.  2015-08-18 01:48:19

Comment: @Paul Check out the examples in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) for bind result, and follow those. They should steer you in the right direction.

Comment: If I am not doing a fetch, then why is all of my data showing up correctly? I just don't get why that would fix this issue, when the correct date IS showing up

Comment: No idea, that really depends on what you're doing with the rest of your code.

Comment: My apologies... I have the fetch in there. It was down farther. Not sure how I missed it. I updated my question.

Comment: @JonStirling Any idea now that I updated the code?

Comment: @Paul you have to echo the $row["date"] value, not the $announcements_date

Comment: @paul instead of `<?php echo $announcements_date; ?>`, try `<?php echo fixDate($announcements_date); ?>` You can then probably get rid of the lines `$announcements_stmt->store_result();` to the original `fixDate` line.

Comment: @JonStirling Perfect. How can I get the date to format in the correct time zone though? I am in the US EST. This prints AM instead of PM and one hour behind.

Comment: @Paul That depends on how you've stored the date. If you're storing them as UTC (or another _known_ timezone) you can probably use the examples on the [DateTime setTimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) documentation page.

Comment: @Paul I'd suggest you open the query about timezones in a new question. The comment thread has already become too long and that this goes a bit off topic for the original question it seems a perfect chance to get some more specific help on that issue. Especially since timezones can be an absolute nightmare.

Comment: I store the date in my database as the Date format.

Comment: Ok, feel free to answer the question with your answer and I will award it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when using `bind_result()`, you need to do a `fetch()` before the variables get populated. In this case, you're trying to access them before that happens.

In the given code, it's not necessary to get the fixed $announcements_date outside the while loop, so just replacing `<?php echo $announcements_date; ?>` with `<?php echo fixDate($announcements_date); ?>` in the loop should do the trick.